# save all inputs as list

Tags: list-manipulation, data

I received three results of calculations:

> ```
> {k->0.190729}
>
> {k->0.197575}
>
> {k->0.249319}
> ```

Could you help me write the results in the following form:

> ```
> {0.190729,0.197575,0.249319}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

For illustrative purposes:

```
Solve[(r - 1) (r - 2) (r - 4) == 0, r]
```

yields: {{r -> 1}, {r -> 2}, {r -> 4}}

```
r /. Solve[(r - 1) (r - 2) (r - 4) == 0, r]
```

yields: {1, 2, 4}

If you want  to transform:{{r -> 1}, {r -> 2}, {r -> 4}}

all the following produce {1,2,4} (the first seems simplest):

```
r /. {{r -> 1}, {r -> 2}, {r -> 4}}
#[[1, 2]] & /@ {{r -> 1}, {r -> 2}, {r -> 4}}
Last /@ Flatten[{{r -> 1}, {r -> 2}, {r -> 4}}]
Flatten[#[[All, 2]] & /@ {{r -> 1}, {r -> 2}, {r -> 4}}]
```

Comment: Why not doing a Community Wiki since it's a clear duplicate, and since it can be easily found in the documentation?

Comment: @Öskå sorry...agree easily found in documentation and sadly do not known what `doing a Community Wiki` means...apologies for ignorance. Aim was just to facilitate OP understanding...happy to be referred to duplicate

Comment: And @ubpdqn there is a little box "Community Wiki" between the editable text and the preview :) And I do agree on the fact you did provide a clear answer :)